# R: tidy() an aovlist-object using the broom package

Tags: r

I have had some trouble tidying `avolist` objects. When performing a repeated measures analysis of variance the optput object is usually a list of `aov` objects for the different error strata.

```
datafilename <- "http://personality-project.org/r/datasets/R.appendix5.data"
aov_example <- read.table(datafilename, header = T)
aov_example <- aov(Recall ~ (Task*Valence*Gender*Dosage) + Error(Subject/(Task*Valence)) +(Gender*Dosage), aov_example)
class(aov_example)
```

> [1] "aovlist" "listof"

(example stolen from http://personality-project.org/r/#anova)

To-date, it is not possible to tidy these objects directly because `broom::fix_data_frame()` doesn't take lists.

```
library("broom")
tidy(aov_example)
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
>    cannot coerce class "c("aovlist", "listof")" to a data.frame

So I tried to use `lapply()`, but this throws an error:

```
lapply(aov_example, tidy)
```

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("df", "sumsq", "meansq", "statistic",  : 
>    Attribute 'names' [5] must be of same length as vector [3]

Is there an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `tidy.aovlist` method [has been added](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom/issues/26) to broom as of [version 0.3.6](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom/releases/tag/v0.3.6), so that one can simply do:

```
tidy(aov_example)
```

without needing `lapply`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
lapply(summary(aov_example),function(x){tidy(x[[1]])})
```

It will give you a list of datatables with the degrees of freedom, sum of squares..